# syncronize icloud contacts with iphone contacts

Tags: icloud, contacts, iphone

I have contacts on my iPhone6 that don't appear when I search for them in contacts on icloud (as in the website).  How can I get my phone accounts to get into the cloud?

Tried so far: went into iPhone Settings -> Contacts -> Default Account and selected 'iCloud'.  This apparently had no effect.

I restarted my iphone and verified that 'iCloud' is still listed as my default Contacts account.  After re-loading icloud.com, still some contacts are not appearing.

Update:  iOS version 10.3.2.  I also verified that contacts is turned on.  Changing the title to reflect that I don't see a problem with my phone -- the problem is that icloud is not seeing the contacts with my phone.  So the problem is icloud.  Of course, the broken link could be anywhere, including my phone.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention what version of iOS you're using so I'm assuming you're using the latest version.  Be sure you follow these directions from [Apple's support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205754) to setup the sync between your iPhone and iCloud:

## Get started

- **Make sure that you’re signed in to iCloud with the same Apple ID on all of your devices**.
- Set up iCloud on all of your devices. If you have a PC, download iCloud for Windows.
- Make sure that you're connected to Wi-Fi or have an active Internet or cellular connection.

### Set up iCloud Contacts

When you turn on iCloud Contacts, all of the information stored on separate devices uploads to iCloud. If you turn off iCloud Contacts, your information won't automatically move from iCloud back to your device.

### On your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch

- Go to `Settings > [your name] > iCloud`. If you’re using iOS 10.2 or earlier, go to `Settings > iCloud`.
- Turn on **Contacts**.
- When you're asked if you want to Merge or Cancel, tap Merge.

All of the information stored in Contacts uploads to iCloud.

### On iCloud.com or iCloud for Windows

After you turn on iCloud Contacts on your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, or Mac, your contacts upload to iCloud. You can find and edit your contacts on iCloud.com or in iCloud for Windows. Any changes that you make automatically update on your other devices.

If you turn off iCloud Contacts on your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, or Mac, your contacts won't delete from iCloud, they won't update automatically, and any changes you make won't update across your other devices.

---

If this doesn't work, follow the troubleshooting steps on [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203521).  There's many steps to try and options to take so I can't list them in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

To test that basic contact syncing was working, I created a new contact on my iphone and observed that it quickly appeared on icloud.com.

However, I still observed that a specific contact on my iphone was not appearing on icloud.com.  Based on a conversation with Apple Support, some contacts are impossible to sync if they originated with some other app such as Facebook or WhatsApp.

I don't remember the origin of my 'problem contact', but I re-entered it manually and that solved the problem.  The Apple Support person suggested that manual re-entry is the easiest method that exists.